# rails combine the mail_to and button_to together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

In rails, now I have mail_to, it shows up purely as a link, when i click on it, it leads me to my email application. how can i change it to a button using twitter bootstrap?

now i have

```
 = mail_to @my.email, "#{@my.name}",:subject=>@my.email_subject
```

Anyway to change the link appear as a button?

I tried out the following

```
  = button_to @my.email, "#{@my.name}",:subject=>@my.email_subject
```

but it still doesnt work....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `= mail_to @my.email, "#{@my.name}",:subject=>@my.email_subject, :class => 'button'`

Hence, you must have some CSS which defines the class `button`.

Comment: You could attach a on click listener on that button, which makes an ajax call to an action within your controller, where it can record that the user has clicked the mail_to link.